# Toyota Avensis feels like it will roll on roundabouts

Tags: steering, avensis

It's a 2006 Toyota Avensis and I've had it for 5 years. It had its service a couple of weeks ago and since then it's started feeling like it's about to roll on roundabouts. I'm not going slowly but I'm also not going particularly fast. Any ideas?

The one thing I know it doesn't get when it is serviced is wheel alignment. Could that be the cause?

Comment: What do you mean by "feels like it's going to roll?"

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica - I'd assume the OP means there is a lot of body roll, which makes it feel like they are going to tip the vehicle over during hard cornering.

Comment: Sounds like you have a suspension issue of some sort.  It seems to me the most likely causes of this are weakened or broken springs, worn out struts/shock absorbers, a broken or damaged sway bar.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 That was my first thought as well...but then I wondered if, perhaps, the OP wasn't conversant with car handling words.

Comment: @jwh20 Thank you very much. Some of those options sound more expensive than others.

Comment: @sdexp Yes, some of those are certainly more expensive than others.  But then an accident caused by driving a car in need of repair can be very expensive and dangerous as well.

Comment: Replacing the cheapest parts doesn't fix the problem. Replacing the right parts corrects the problem.